# Camera button on UIImagePickerController is randomly disbled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController (source type camera) that I use to take pictures. I have it put properly in my .h (added the @property) and .m (@synthesize). Here's what I use to show it:

```
if (thePicker == nil) {
thePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
thePicker.delegate = self;
thePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
thePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
}

[self presentModalViewController:thePicker animated:YES];
```

I'm having an odd problem. Every now and again, after closing/opening it a few times, the camera button OR the used button won't work (but the retake and cancel buttons work). I'm not getting any memory warnings and I have a dealloc and didReceiveMemoryWarnings void statement, but they don't get called.

ANyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen some apps cover it up with their overlay, but you can't remove it. AVCaptureSession really does sound more appropriate for your purposes. I see one example here:

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273

Try this it may help u i guess Thanks!!